# How to process dataflow two batch files simultaneously on GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, dataflow, google-dataflow

I want to process two files from gcp to dataflow at the same time simultaneously.

I think it will be possible if one more file comes in side-input.

However, in this case, I think it will be processed every time, not just once.

e.g) How to read and process file1 and file2 at the same time (do I have to put two files in one file and just follow the path?)

I'd appreciate it if you could give me a good example or advice.

Thank you.

Comment: Do  you know the 2 files name before the pipeline start?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere yes, i know 2 files name.

Answer (score 1):

If you know the 2 files from the beginning you can simply have a pipeline with 2 entry (fileIO)

I don't know your language, but by design you can do this

```
     PCollection1                        PCollection2
          |                                   |
   FileIO(readFile1)                   FileIO(readFile2)
          |                                   |
    Transform file                       Transform file
          |                                   |
    WriteIO(sink)                        WriteIO(sink)
```

You can imagine side input, flatten, group by,... all depends on your needs.